# Titlepage and vertical space

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, titles

I need to reduce the vertical space up the title of the only front page. I'm using the book class and specifically the titlepage enviroment. \vspace{-2.0cm} doesn't work...
Any suggestion?

Comment: If you are using the `titlepage` environment, you are setting stuff up by hand. Are you at the top of the page? If so, use `\vspace*{2cm}`. If not, please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: You might be interested in [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280) as well.

Comment: Your first comment solved my question!

Answer (score 2):

Do that with the `titling` package: it defines a `\droptitle` length which you can choose at will. Example of use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{lmodern} %
\usepackage[top=33mm, bottom=38mm, left=26mm, right=20mm, showframe]{geometry} %
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\bfseries\LARGE\color{IndianRed3}}%
\posttitle{\end{center}\mdseries}
\droptitle = -20mm
\title{A Subtitle}%
\author{Author names}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Blahblahblah…

\end{document}
```

[image]